# Combine Select SQL into Single Query w/ Mutiple Columns

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, select

This multiple SELECT QUERY runs consecutively.  I need one report with multiple columns for [GBPMID] and [EURMID].

Query 1

```
SELECT
    (([askPrice] - [bidPrice]) / 2) + [bidPrice] AS [EURMID]
    FROM TicksForex 
        WHERE [Symbol] = 'EUR/USD' 
        AND [Time] >= CONVERT(datetime, '6/6/2011 12:00 AM')
```

Query 2

```
SELECT
     [Time]
    ,[askPrice]
    ,[bidPrice]
    ,(([askPrice] - [bidPrice]) / 2) + [bidPrice] AS [GBPMID]
    FROM TicksForex 
        WHERE [Symbol] = 'GBP/USD'  
        AND [Time] >= CONVERT(datetime, '6/6/2011 12:00 AM')
```

@Pranay & @Magnus - MY APOLOGIES!  My Data tables do not share the same TIME Values... which was a surprise to me.. this is why the records do not line up.. so sorry!!  I will run this as @Pranay describes below...

Forget it!  It normalized the data (date) so they all shared the same date - ie.. updated prices at the same time.. and it still does not work!!

Comment: added output from answer below from @Pranay

Comment: try the modified query again this might work perfectly............

Comment: @Pranay - its getting closer - see output above (thank you for your help  !!)

Comment: What are your source table values?

Comment: @Pranay & @Magnus - MY APOLOGIES!  My Data tables do not share the same TIME Values... which was a surprise to me.. this is why the records do not line up.. so sorry!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of [`Case...when`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) will resolve you issue easily

```
SELECT
     [Time]
    ,[askPrice]
    ,[bidPrice],

  ( CASE WHEN Symbol = 
          'GBP/USD' THEN ((([askPrice] - [bidPrice]) / 2) + [bidPrice])
         ELSE 0
      END) AS [GBPMID],
  ( CASE WHEN Symbol =
           'EUR/USD' THEN ((([askPrice] - [bidPrice]) / 2) + [bidPrice])
         ELSE 0
      END) AS [EURMID]

    FROM TicksForex 
        WHERE ([Symbol] = 'GBP/USD'  or [Symbol] = 'EUR/USD' )
        AND [Time] >= CONVERT(datetime, '6/6/2011 12:00 AM')
```

Comment: CASE assumes you want multiple expressions and one input this is the same expression with multiple inputs so I could not get it to work.. example ??

Comment: just needs to commas before each (CASE... but for some strange reason I am getting

Comment: a strange ouput... it seems to combine onto one row then adds '0' in every other row or sometimes every row   
See question edit above...

Comment: @CraigJSte  Make use of sum as i did

Comment: @Pranay - it give me an "Time Column invalid in Select because it must be in GROUP by clause or Aggregate function'  ??  CHECKING NEW EDIT ..... :)  Disregard...

Comment: @Pranay - getting closer... Now output is on separate lines .. any way to make the ouput share the same line for each ?  The zeros are a big problem for me.  (adding out put above )

Comment: @Pranay & @Magnus - MY APOLOGIES!  My Data tables do not share the same TIME Values... which was a surprise to me.. this is why the records do not line up.. so sorry!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM
    (SELECT
        [Symbol],
        [Time],
        [askPrice],
        [bidPrice],
        ([askPrice] - [bidPrice]) / 2 As calc
    FROM 
        TicksForex
    WHERE 
       ([Symbol] = 'GBP/USD'  or [Symbol] = 'EUR/USD') AND
       [Time] >= CONVERT(datetime, '6/6/2011 12:00 AM')) As srcTable
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(calc)
        FOR Symbol IN([EUR/USD], [GBP/USD])
    ) As PivotTable
```

Comment: Same issue sym's on diff lines with 0s where omitted.

Comment: If you remove [Time],[askPrice],[bidPrice] you will get one row. But than you have to decide how you want to aggregate multiple values of the same currency (max, sum, min...)

Comment: @Pranay & @Magnus - MY APOLOGIES!  My Data tables do not share the same TIME Values... which was a surprise to me.. this is why the records do not line up.. so sorry!!